# prevent some parts of html from showing in code retrieved from remote page using curl

Tags: php, html, regex, curl

I am retreiving source code from remote page using curl then echo it in my page using `echo $html` but this echo the whole remote page . what i am tring to do is to prebvent some parts

from being echod in my page (the ads that are in the remote pageand some other parts) the remote page code is almost like that

```
<IFRAME FRAMEBORDER=0 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 SCROLLING=NO WIDTH=728 HEIGHT=90 SRC="http://creative.xtendmedia.com/proxy/matomymediaproxy.html?ad_type=ad&ad_size=728x90&section=2650714"></IFRAME>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youradexchange.com/script/java.php?option=rotateur&rotateur=83132"></script>

<script language="JavaScript"> var zflag_nid="1723"; var zflag_cid="18"; var zflag_sid="0"; var zflag_width="1"; var zflag_height="1"; var zflag_sz="15"; </script>

<script language="JavaScript" src="http://c1.zxxds.net/jsc/c1/fo.js"></script>
```

i currently use `preg_match_all('#(<iframe.*myspecificword.*/iframe>)#i', $html, $matches);
var_dump($matches);`

but its not effective as the the specfic word differs every time .

is there is any other better ways provided that the part of the code i want do display only is always the line no 59 ? how can echo this line only?

Comment: any suggestion for showing specific line no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something similar to Python [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html), but for PHP, like [this](http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html). Anyway, it is probably using a regex under the hood, so it might not be faster than your solution. Certainly, it's cleaner.

EDIT: I discourage this, but if you know that you script will be **always** line 59 of the file and a single line only, then read it line by line discarding the first 58, like this:

```
$stream = fopen('http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php', 'r');

if (!$stream) {
    // Report error
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 58; $i++) {
    fgets($stream);
}

// Here is line 59
$myline = fgets($stream);

echo $myline;
```

You might have to expand the recognized line terminators list with:

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',true);
```

Instead, if the page is a string, then use `explode()` to break it at line terminators and then select the 59th element of the returned array.

Comment: here the whole code is there is something wrong? 
    `$html = file_get_contents($newurl);
 for ($i = 0; $i < 58; $i++) {
    fgets($file_you_are_reading);
}

// Here is line 59
$myline = fgets($file_you_are_reading);
    echo $myline;
?>` i have trimmed part of the code so the comment cant take more charchters

Comment: Add this line before the code posted above: `$file_you_are_reading = fopen('http://theurlyouaretryingtoopen.com');` Adjust the url.

Comment: Why downvoted? Solution above is discouraged but works as expected.

Comment: thank u sir your code works but if i get the url dynamically i mean not a fixed url it not works look at the code below `<?php
$keys = array('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel'); // order does matter
$stream = fopen('http://remotesite/static/popups/');
foreach ($keys as $key)
    $stream .= empty($_REQUEST[$key])?0:$_REQUEST[$key];

$stream .='.html';

if (!$stream) {
    // Report error
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 58; $i++) {
    fgets($stream);
}

// Here is line 59
$myline = fgets($stream);
echo $myline
?>` what is the problem with that

Comment: If I understand right, you want to open a different url every time: you **must** modify `'http://remotesite/static/popups/'`, not `$stream`. `$stream` is not a string, is a handle to remote file.

Comment: yes the url will differs according to the values of the arrays ('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel') this arrays is got using $_get from the url the user click. how i add these arrays to your code

Comment: Replace `'http://remotesite/static/popups/'` with a variable, say, `$url_to_open` and modify that before using it in `fopen`.

Comment: here its but still not working : `<?php
$keys = array('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel'); // order does matter
$newurl = 'http://remotesite/static/popups/';
foreach ($keys as $key)
    $newurl.= empty($_REQUEST[$key])?0:$_REQUEST[$key];

$newurl.='.html';

$stream = fopen('$newurl', 'r');

if (!$stream) {
    // Report error
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 58; $i++) {
    fgets($stream);
}

// Here is line 59
$myline = fgets($stream);

echo $myline;
?>`

Comment: Don't add `0`, add `''`. However, this makes for another question. This specific problem is closed, if you need help ask another, separate question. Thanks.

Comment: can you update your code above also take a look on this the new separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443223/using-curl-to-get-remote-page-source-how-to-echo-only-one-line-of-the-code-based