# Using Curl to get remote page source how to echo only one line of the code based on its number

Tags: php, html, regex, curl

I am working n getting the source code of remote page the url of that remote page it got dynamically from the url the user click according to the arrays `array('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel')` : i use the code below to get the who;e page source and it works great.

```
<?php
$keys = array('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel'); // order does matter
$newurl = 'http://lsh.streamhunter.eu/static/popups/';
foreach ($keys as $key)
    $newurl.= empty($_REQUEST[$key])?0:$_REQUEST[$key];

$newurl.='.html';
    function get_data($newurl) 
    { 
       $ch = curl_init();
       $timeout = 5;
       //$userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.X.Y.Z Safari/525.13.";
       $userAgent = "IE 7 – Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$newurl);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
      $data = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      return $data;

    }

    $html = get_data($newurl);

    echo $html

?>
```

the trick here is that i want to echo only line no 59 of the code 
how to do so?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you ever *call* `get_data`

Comment: does line 59 have some id or class? if yes, you should try dom parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using `file_get_contents` instead of the `get_data` function so I removed it from the example.

```
<?php
    $keys = array('event_id', 'tv_id', 'tid', 'channel'); // order does matter
    $newurl = 'http://lsh.streamhunter.eu/static/popups/';
    foreach ($keys as $key)
        $newurl.= empty($_REQUEST[$key])?0:$_REQUEST[$key];

    $newurl.='.html';


    $html = file_get_contents($newurl);
    $html = explode("\n",$html);
    echo $html[58];

?>
```

Comment: it worked now after some tweaks if i want more than one line how to separate them in `echo $html[58];`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the php function [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read a file into an array, and then use its index.

```
$html = file($newurl);

echo $html[58];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get exactly line 59 of the data returned from `$newurl` and you're not worried about it being that large, you could just use `file($newurl)[58]`.

If you're talking about the data from `curl`, you can use `explode("\n", $data)` to get a similar array.

Comment: i have upadted the code in the question to get_data can  sir suggest me code to display only line no 59